# Migrate complex svn structure to git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration

I'm working on the conversion of a group of old svn repositories into git. The current svn structure looks like this:

```
/RootRepository  
    /FatClient  
        /branches  
            /1.1  
            /1.2  
        /tags  
            /1.1.1  
            /1.1.2  
        /trunk  
    /WebApp  
        /branches  
            /1.1  
            /1.2  
        /tags  
            /1.1.1  
            /1.1.2  
        /trunk  
    /CommonLibrary  
        /branches  
            /1.1  
            /1.2  
        /tags  
            /1.1.1  
            /1.1.2  
        /trunk
```

When working on the new bits, the development team checks out:

```
/RootRepository/FatClient/trunk
/RootRepository/WebApp/trunk
/RootRepository/CommonLibrary/trunk
```

Changes are made very frequently across the three "projects" which results in 3 commits, and (because they are in the same repository on the server) each commit gets the next sequential revision. The three projects are always released together as components of an Application.

I would like to migrate from the svn structure with history into a single git structure that looks like this:

```
/RootRepository  
    /master
        /FatClient
        /WebApp
        /CommonLibrary
    /branch-1.1
        /FatClient
        /WebApp
        /CommonLibrary
    /branch-1.2
        /FatClient
        /WebApp
        /CommonLibrary
```

When I run:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout https://somesvnserver.com/RootRepository/FatClient  
git svn clone --stdlayout https://somesvnserver.com/RootRepository/WebApp  
git svn clone --stdlayout https://somesvnserver.com/RootRepository/CommonLibrary
```

I end up with 3 git repositories with trunk, branches and history. If I run:

```
git svn clone https://somesvnserver.com/RootRepository
```

I have 1 git repository with history, but all the code is in master.

So, the question is: what is the best way to achieve this while retaining the svn history.

Comment: `git svn clone <SVN repo URL>` can also migrate svn repo to git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian provides [migration scripts](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/svn-migration-scripts/src) to help you migrate your existing development workflow from `SVN` to `Git` along with the write up to use them [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/svn-to-git-prepping-your-team-migration).

I too written blog long time back which can help you to achieve what you are looking for here - [Migrating from SVN to Git](https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/migrating-from-svn-to-git/) .